# Prevents screen snapshot

Tags: java, android, security, screenshot, snapshot

I have an Android banking app that prevents from taking a snapshot of the screen how do I do that in my own app.

Does anyone know how this is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by adding a simple code in the activity

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Just add FLAG_SECURE flag in the activity. It Works for all Android versions  higher than HONEYCOMB ie API 11 or higher.

Window flag: treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.

Thsi prevents screenrecording and screenshots